# MySQL trigger regexp not working

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, triggers, phpmyadmin

I am trying to group users by their email address.
REGEXP is not working. Help

```
BEGIN

DECLARE group_id tinyint(4);

SET @user_email = ( SELECT email FROM `users` WHERE id = NEW.id );

IF (SELECT @user_email REGEXP '\.com$') THEN SET group_id  = 17;
ELSE SET group_id  = 18;
END IF;

INSERT INTO `user_usergroup_map` (`user_id`, `group_id`) VALUES (NEW.id, group_id);

END
```

--------- New -------------------
I did some more testing.

This worked...

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `user_usergroup_map` (`user_id`, `group_id`) VALUES( 3, 18 );
END
```

But this didn't work

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `user_usergroup_map` (`user_id`, `group_id`) VALUES( 
    NEW.id, 18);
END
```

Comment: "Not working" -- Crash server?  Get error?  Get wrong answer?  What answer is wrong?  `SELECT 'a.com' REGEXP '\.com$', 'a.org' REGEXP '\.com$';` --> 1, 0; so it looks good.  Consider changing `\.` to `[.]`.

Comment: @RickJames i didn't get any error messages, no crash. Simply, no new insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try to figure out what is not working, let me suggest this simplification:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `user_usergroup_map` (`user_id`, `group_id`)
        SELECT NEW.id,
               IF( email REGEXP '[.]com$', 17, 18 )
            FROM users
            WHERE id = NEW.id;
END
```

One difference:  Your version will always insert a row; mine won't if `id` is missing from `users`.

Comment: And you are sure the `id` did exist in `users` but did not already exist in `user_usergroup_map`?

Comment: yes. usergroup_map is keyed to user_id and group_id. The user can have more than one group_id but not the same group_id.

Comment: it worked.. i was adding the trigger to the wrong table.